# Need some explanation regarding the working of following Typescript/Javascript and MobX code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

The following code was used to create an array containing object groups(arrays) by date. I could understand the intention but could not understand the working of the code. This is from a course by "Neil Cummings" and unfortunately I could not find his SO handle to ask him directly. Also I borrowed the course so I couldn't ask him through Q & A either.
So please consider explaining the code to me.

```
@computed get activitiesByDate() {
    return this.groupActivitiesByDate(Array.from(this.activityRegistry.values()));
}

groupActivitiesByDate(activites: IActivity[]){
    const sortedActivities = activites.sort(
      (a,b) => Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date)
    )
    return Object.entries(sortedActivities.reduce((activities, activity) => { 
      const date = activity.date.split('T')[0];
      activities[date] = activities[date] ? [...activities[date], activity]: [activity];
      return activities;
    }, {} as {[key: string]: IActivity[]}));
  }
```

In the code above I could understand that a new array i.e. "sortedActivities" is made by sorting the activities array. Then again the reduce function is called on it where part of date from each activity is split to find objects having same date and grouping them - which is where Object.entries comes in. What I couldn't understand how the ordering of "activites" array is affecting "sortedActivities" when actually we are sorting the activities array and also the line when ternary operator is being used. can we compare two arrays directly like that? if so why get each object from the array?. I am totally confused I tried to search some similar code to get a nice and clear explanation but I couldn't find any. Can any body please help me out. I hope I have provided enough information for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's go line by line:

```js
const sortedActivities = activites.sort(
  (a,b) => Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date)
)
```

Here we sort an array of activities by date, pretty simple. By there is also a very rookie mistake here (not quite sure how course author could make it), is that `.sort` actually mutates original array. So it is quite bad to call it like that, you need to call `.slice()` first to create new separate copy.

```
sortedActivities.reduce((activities, activity) => { 
  const date = activity.date.split('T')[0];
  activities[date] = activities[date] ? [...activities[date], activity]: [activity];
  return activities;
}, {} as {[key: string]: IActivity[]})
```

Then we make map of array of activities grouped by same date, so it it will be something like that in the end:

```
const reduceResult = {
  // Might be different format for date, but you see the point
  '2020-08-10': [activity, activity],
  '2020-09-10': [activity],
  '2020-10-10': [],
  // ...
}
```

So this line:

```
activities[date] = activities[date] ? [...activities[date], activity]: [activity];
```

just checks if array with `date` key already exists, if not it creates new array, if it exists then it just merges old array with current `activity`

Then we return `Object.entries`

```
Object.entries(...)
```

Basically just grabbing all values from our map.

But there is another possible mistake (or bug) here, because author of the code assumes that creating map from sorted array will always be sorted too, but it is not, `Object.entries` iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order, so you should not depend on that, even if it work for this case right now.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. 
But "activities[date] = activities[date]" is quite confusing, because it implies I am accessing a value in activities array with certain date and the confusion is because activities is actually holding individual activities (JavaScript objects) and not dates. Can you point me to some code where I can upgrade from old school iteration techniques to these new ones. I like old school because it is intuitive.

Comment: No, `activities` is reduce accumulator, it is equal to empty array at first, and then you fill inside reduce. Maybe reading about reduce documentation would help? Or I can make some additional example

Comment: No fine, I guess I lack knowledge of reduce function and referring to documentation might help me understand it, and thank you very much for providing information on rookie mistakes as well. Much appreciated.